# How to insert an output of a sma into math.sum function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm struggling with pine script and I haven't found a way to insert an output of a sma into a math.sum function

Any help would very appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague - but this is the concept

```
   out_ = math.sum(sma_, length)
```